# ¿Como obtener mas campos en el return del autocomplete UI JQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método autocomplete de *JQuery UI* que me retorna 2 campos *id* y *label*. Pero yo quiero que me retorne mas campos aparte de los mencionado, por ejemplo idTarifa,nombreTarifa, ya que al dar el evento select pueda obtener esos valores demás.

Aquí esta mi método autocomplete.

```
$("#nombreColaborador1").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: root + "MantEmpleado/ListarEmpleadoAutocompletable2",
                        data: { parametro: request.term },
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET",
                        async: false,
                        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (json) {
                            console.log(json);
                            response($.map(json.data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Nombre,
                                    id: item.IdExterno
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#IdColaborador2").val(i.item.id);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu JSON que retornas los datos  desde el backend
y para leerlos de la misma manera

```
var idTicket = i.item.idTicket;
$("#IdTicket").val(idTicket);
```

Comment: Mi json retorna más campos he intente hacerlo como tu lo has hecho pero no me devuelve el valor

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), te recomiendo explicar mejor tu respuesta.